# Make jQuery.sticky() keep elements as they were horizontaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, sticky

While using a Sticky Plugin v1.0.0, I got to the problem with smart phones respectively small windows sizes - and I noticed that when the window is so small that the "sticked" element wouldn't be completely shown, the element's left side is "sticked" to the left side of the window - I checked the CSS applied and noticed that default sticky behaviour only sets the TOP,

is there a way to retian the elements in their original horizontal (X coordinate) position even when the window is smaller?

Thanks in advance.

PS: using Sticky Plugin v1.0.0 for jQuery (by Anthony Garand)

**Code** - my sticky code would look like this:

```
$element.sticky({bottomSpacing:510});
```

**EDIT**

Sadly, as I found out on github, current version of jQuery Sticky only affects `position` and `top`. Which is actually enaugh if your page "fits" to the window.

Comment: Have you tried just doing position=fixed? Is that what you're going for? Can you show us some code?

Comment: No it is not, check the "sticky" functionality, ´position: fixed;` doesnt do the "sticky" effect...